# Google Geocoding multiple results for precise address

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I'm using the maps API to embed driving directions within an application. We use the geocoding API to confirm the address before building the route, but recently this has developed a problem with increasing frequency.

I'm confident the address we're passing in is correct.  I am passing an exact postal address, including city, state, and zip code.  The Geocoding API is returning 2 results.  One identical to the one I passed in, and one with a similar street name, but a different city and state.  The wrong result is returned first, followed by the correct result.

I won't post an example here due to it being a private residence, but  I'll go so far as to say that the correct address is something like 123 mountain road, Pittsburg, PA.  The first result returned by the geocode is at 123 South Mountain Road, Washington, PA, and then followed by a second result of the correct one.

The multiple search results is causing me a huge headache. We have a separate process that validates the address when it's first put in to make sure that it's exactly correct per the maps API.  The customer may have put in 123 Mountaim Road, and the system would pop a dialog for them to choose the correct one,(using the api) then actually save the selected correct address instead of the input.  then that saved correct address is passed into routing and is still coming up with multiple results.

Comment: Did you consider using Place autocomplete? This way user chooses address they are interested in from autocomplete, you can pick up the selected place id and pass this place id to directions service as origin or destination. Using place id from place autocomplete you can solve ambiguous addresses.

Comment: Except that it isn't ambigious. The address that's stored was selected as a place from Place Autocomplete, and the search results I'm getting back is one that is exactly the same as submitted, and one that's in another city with a different zip code that there's no reason for it to even be suggested as an alternate other than something has changed wiht  Geolocation.  The documentation for Geolocation says it returns 1 or 0 results.

Comment: If I cache the place ID in the database, will it remain the same indefinitely? Or will the user be required to go through a list of, say, 15 addresses, and pick the correct one each time they try to generate a route?

Comment: According to Google docs you can store a place ID value in cache indefinitely: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/policies#pre-fetching,-caching,-or-storage-of-content. If Google doesn't remove place from their database the place ID should remain the same.